# No consigo que funcione pyspark en windows 10

Tags: python, windows10, anaconda, pyspark

Estoy intentando instalar pyspark en mi ordenador. Primero lo intenté con Anaconda, después eliminé Anaconda e instalé Python en el ordenador, pero me aparece siempre el mismo fallo y no encuentro una solución por ningún lado.
Adjunto imágen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, spark-shell sí que me funciona.
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Configuré hace un año en windows, con anaconda, siguiendo estos pasos:

1. Instalar Java JDK 8.
2. Descargar el paquete Spark de la página oficial: http://spark.apache.org/downloads.
3. Programación con pyspark (API Python para Spark): En 2019, la versión v2.4 de Apache Spark daba algunos problemas de configuración en Windows 7/8/10. ( supongo que ya no sucede) pero puedes intentar usar la versión v2.3.2 en su lugar.

4.Buscar en el menú de Inicio, dentro de la carpeta Anaconda, el programa Anaconda Prompt. Crear el entorno nuevo para pyspark (también puedes hacerlo directamente desde Anaconda Navigator):

```
conda create -n pyspark anaconda
```

5. Cerrar esa ventana y abrir el programa Anaconda Prompt (pyspark). Nos abre una terminal de línea de comandos, pero ahora en el entorno virtual pyspark.
6. Instalamos el módulo pyspark con el paquete de conda.(Ejemplo para 2.3.2):

   conda install pyspark=2.3.2
7. Finalmente, arrancar Jupyter o JupyterLab desde Anaconda Navigator y debería estar listo para trabajar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, ha sido de gran ayuda. Saludos!